# Adding leftmargin to algorithmic

Tags: margins, algorithmic

How do I set the left margin of an algorithm typeset with `algorithmic` so that the whole thing moves to the right?

I've tried changing `\leftmargin` inside an `algorithmic` block, but it did not work.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\bf function}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\bf end}
    \def\PROCEDURE{\normalfont\REQUIRE}
    \def\ENDPROCEDURE{\ENSURE~}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
Before
\begin{algorithmic}\leftmargin=3em
\PROCEDURE $sign(X)$
    \IF {$X < 0$}
        \RETURN $-1$
    \ELSIF {$X > 0$}
        \RETURN $1$
    \ELSE
        \RETURN $0$
    \ENDIF
\ENDPROCEDURE
\end{algorithmic}
After
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the `\itemindent` inside `algorithmic` environment, as it uses `\list` internally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\bf function}
    \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\bf end}
    \def\PROCEDURE{\normalfont\REQUIRE}
    \def\ENDPROCEDURE{\ENSURE~}
    \algsetup{indent=11pc}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
Before
\begin{algorithmic}\itemindent=10pc
\PROCEDURE $sign(X)$
    \IF {$X < 0$}
        \RETURN $-1$
    \ELSIF {$X > 0$}
        \RETURN $1$
    \ELSE
        \RETURN $0$
    \ENDIF
\ENDPROCEDURE
\end{algorithmic}
After
\end{document}
```

Comment: it almost works, but it does not affect the `RETURN` statements.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You could adjust `\algsetup{indent=length}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with an `algorithmic` that doesn't break across the page boundary, you can set the entire thing inside a `varwidth` box. Then you can move it around in whichever way you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{function}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{end}}
\newcommand{\PROCEDURE}{\normalfont\REQUIRE}
\newcommand{\ENDPROCEDURE}{\ENSURE~}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

Before\strut

\hspace{3em}%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \PROCEDURE $sign(X)$\strut
    \IF {$X < 0$}
      \RETURN $-1$
    \ELSIF {$X > 0$}
      \RETURN $1$
    \ELSE
      \RETURN $0$
    \ENDIF
  \ENDPROCEDURE\strut
\end{algorithmic}
\end{varwidth}

After
\end{document}
```

I've added some `\strut`s to ensure a proper baseline skipping, specifically on the first and last line of the `algorithmic`, as well as possibly before/after it, depending whether the content does not have/has descenders/ascenders. This is to avoid the box being set too close (vertically) to other content above/below it.